# CakePHP - JsHelper::event returns null

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to use the JsHelper::event method on my app, using the same code of the CookBook:

```
$this->Js->get('#element');
$ev = $this->Js->event('click', $this->Js->alert('hey you!'));
```

I try to run `debug($ev)`, but it returns `null`. In the controller, I am adding the helper like this:

```
var $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));
```

How do I get the JsHelper::event to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the JsHelper buffers those calls, hence the `null` return. You can return it inline if you want by setting `'buffer' => false` in your options.

See the book for more information: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#javascript-engine-usage